# 404 Errors after renaming htaccess to reroute from 403 (can't access Wordpress wp-admin)

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-403

The website I'm working on went down last week from a spike in traffic (I think it was a DNS attack based on the logs).

I fixed it and have the main index page up after renaming the `.htaccess` to `htaccess.txt` in their `public_html` folder.

The main index is fine. It works on all the links that take the user to different sections, but when clicking through to an interior page, there's a 404 now.

I can't figure out how to reroute it.

I added

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

to the `htaccess.txt`, but I also get

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home3/login/public_html/wp-load.php:117) in /home3/login/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1174
```

when hitting `wp-admin`.

EDIT: after digging in on the PHP files, we realized it was a malware attack that started the whole thing. We got the htaccess and 403/404 stuff fixed, but since we're launching a wholly new site soon (on Rails rather than WP), there's not a lot of sense in digging through corrupted PHP. Thanks for all your help, folks.

Comment: `htaccess.txt` means nothing to the server , it's just normal text file in this case. You should rename it to `.htaccess` without `.txt`

Comment: Weirdly enough, renaming it to .txt from .htaccess removed the 403. Then renaming it to .htaccess made the 404 go away.

Comment: Leave the `.htaccess` as it is now, and read the answer below posted by Duane Lortie

Answer (score 2):

Inspect both the files mentioned in the error. Likely wp-load.php has been hacked, and even though the nastyness may have been removed, it is sending output to the browser BEFORE WP tries to start a session.  Inspect those files, check for blank lines before and after the opening/closing PHP tags.  You might also consider downloading ALL files that make up that site and running a good virus scanner over it all.

Comment: Will do! Thank you!